# Design Problem: Implementing a two way lookup table in C

Tags: c, algorithm

I want to implement a two way lookup table.
MAC Address --> MAC Address

Means one key can be used to access a value on the upstream side. And on the downstream side, the value can be used to access the key.

Memory is a constraint so I cannot use two hash tables, I am looking forward to use the same nodes of the hash table for both upstream and downstream lookup.

Runtime is a constraint too so only a hash table strategy will work.

Language is a constraint so I can use only C language (so cannot use C++ Boost bimap)

Please share your ideas on how this can be achieved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The constraints sound artificial.  Homework?

Comment: It is a realtime problem, I only explained the constraints in detail for the clarity of reader.

Comment: What format are the MAC addresses?  Strings, or binary values of some specified length?  Can you save enough space by converting from a string to a binary representation?  It is going to be tricky indeed if you really can't afford the complementary hash tables.

Comment: Format of MAC addresses is string. But if converting them to binary for lookup, insert, delete operations can definitely be thought of. Infact binary will probably save some memory too. However, the main problem of some kind of double hash table still holds.

Comment: It's called a quark. Look that up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you suggest, you can use the same nodes for both the upstream and downstream buckets.  It won't save you a huge amount (certainly less than a factor of 2), but anything helps.

```
struct bucket {
  struct bucket *next_upstream;
  struct bucket *next_downstream;
  char upstream_mac[6];
  char downstream_mac[6];
}
struct bucket **upstream_table = malloc(sizeof(struct bucket*) * N);
struct bucket **downstream_table = malloc(sizeof(struct bucket*) * N);
void insert(char *upstream_mac, char *downstream_mac) {
  struct bucket *b = malloc(sizeof(*b));
  memcpy(b->upstream_mac, upstream_mac, 6);
  memcpy(b->downstream_mac, downstream_mac, 6);
  int uh = hash(upstream_mac);
  int dh = hash(downstream_mac);
  b->next_upstream = upstream_table[uh];
  upstream_table[uh] = b;
  b->next_downstream = downstream_table[dh];
  downstream_tbale[dh] = b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you use two parallel arrays? Ie,

```
// assuming no reallocation required
#define BUFFERSIZE some-gigantic-number
char upstream[BUFFERSIZE];
char downstream[BUFFERSIZE];
```

Then layout each list of MAC addresses as consecutive characters. For example:

```
upstream:

"01:23:45:67:89:ab\000:0d:93:81:d9:7c\0..."
 |_______________|  |_______________|
         |                  |
   first address      second address   ...

downstream:

"00:0a:95:d1:52:30\001:45:c3:2d:65:b5\0..."
 |_______________|  |_______________|
         |                  |
   first address      second address   ...
```

Have both `upstream` and `downstream` laid-out this way, where the paired MAC addresses are in the same order.

Now to find the paired MAC address, just use `strcmp()` or similar to check each MAC address within a single array. Once the key is found, the same index in the complementing array is the value.

Why do it this way? It takes almost no auxiliary memory, and it's very cache efficient.

Comment: You could add a cache mechanism to this, if your memory usage restrictions allow it: when you find a MAC address, save the array position in a smaller table indexed by MAC address, and perform queries there first. You can have an upstream and a downstream cache, or only one, depends on usage. You'll have to choose and implement some replacement criterion (LRU, etc)

Comment: @dario This mechanism is already cache-effcient; a small enough buffer should fit entirely in L1 cache. There's no point in adding an LRU-based auxiliary table.

Comment: You're right, although that depends on L1 and array size. Since the OP was worried about memory usage, I'd assumed his arrays would be too big for L1 to hold completely

Comment: strcmp is not runtime efficient as I understand.

Comment: @Groovy Where did you get that from?! Any comparison algorithm you choose will have to loop through the elements of the string. Here's the [code](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/strcmp.c;h=bd53c05c6e21130b091bd75c3fc93872dd71fe4b;hb=HEAD) for `strcmp()`. You're going to need a variation of this anyway.

Comment: This is going to be way too slow if, as the OP says, he has lots of mac addresses.

Comment: @chrisaycock Thanks for your answer. I make myself more clear: I meant looping on all the elements of array doing strcmp will be costlier. That is why I am looking out for some kind of hash table. So that I can directly reach the desired element.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can combine the two head-pointer-arrays into one. It just makes the chains longer, and the code shorter. 
The part of the code that has to retrieve the nodes from the linked lists has to inspect one of the the mac1[], or mac2[] fields anyway, (ignoring the other one)